# In Vue JS , How to display Table Header after getting the Server Response?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, html-table, vuejs3

In My Vue.JS web Page, I have a API Call with Http - GET Method. Before getting API Response, The table header will be displayed by default. This doesn't look good. Could you please help in my below current code, how to display Table header, only after getting server response ? Thanks in advance.

**PackageInfo.vue**

```
<template>
    
<h3> Package List </h3>


<div>

  <br>   <br> <br> 
    <button  @click="fetchPackageIDs"> Get Package IDs </button>

    <br> <br> 
  <table class="table-bordered table-hover table-sm" align="center">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr scope="row" align="center">
     
      <th> Package IDs  </th>
      <th> Package Type  </th>
      <th> State  </th>
      <th> Sub State  </th>
      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr scope="row" align="center" v-for="(user) in posts.packageIDs" :key="user.packageId">
    
      <td>{{ user.packageId }}</td> 
        <td>{{ user.packageType }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.state }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.subState }}</td>
      
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 <br>  <br>   <br>
</div>

</template>

<script>



import { apiHost} from '../config'
import axios from 'axios'


export default {
    name:"PackageInfo",
    data(){
        return{
            posts: {
            
                packageIDs:[]
              
            }
            
        }
    },
    methods:{
        fetchPackageIDs(e){
          const url=apiHost+'tdg/packageIds/'+localStorage.getItem('userId');
          console.log(url);
          e.preventDefault();
              
           axios.get(url,null,null)   
          .then(response=>this.posts.packageIDs=response.data)
          .catch(e => {
                console.log(e); 
          })
          console.log(this.posts.packageIDs);
      
         },
    }
}

</script>



<style >

.form-control:focus{
border-color:#167bff;
box-shadow:none;
}

.auth-inner{

width:450px;
margin :auto;
background: #ffffff;
box-shadow:0px 14px 80px rgba (34,35,58,0.2);
padding:40px 55px 45px 55px;
border-radius:15px;
transition: all .3s;

}

table.table-bordered{
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-top:20px;
  }
table.table-bordered > thead > tr > th{
    border:1px solid black;
    padding: 7px 30px;
}
table.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td{
    border:1px solid black;
    padding: 7px 30px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: You can check the length `v-if="posts.packageIDs.length > 0"` in `thead` or the `table`

Comment: this would fail if the response does not have any packageIds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using the boolean property.

```
<template>
   <div>
      <table v-if="showTable">
         ...
         <tr v-if="posts.packageIDs.length === 0">
             <td colspan={columnsCount}> No Records Found </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</template>
```

---

```
<script>
    export default {
       data () {
          return {
              showTable: false,
              posts: {
                  packageIDs: []
              }
          };
       },
       methods: {
          fetchPackageIDs(e) {
           this.showTable = false;
           axios.get({url})   
          .then(response=>this.posts.packageIDs=response.data)
          .catch(e => {console.log(e);})
          .finally(() => this.showTable = true)
         }
       }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Sowmyadhar Gourishetty , This is working fine. But, in case, of empty response JSON (without displaying Table Header), How to display a simple toast message saying, 'NO Records Available!'?

Comment: I am not getting proper solution for this problem which is on VueJS. Could you please help on this ? Thanks in advance.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68213546/in-vuejs-version-3-what-is-the-correct-way-to-show-and-hide-the-login-logout/68221604?noredirect=1#comment120654976_68221604